# initialize amazon aws cognito client via BasicAWSCredentials vs CognitoAWSCredentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, identity, credentials, amazon-cognito

What is the difference between these two approaches of initializing a new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient?

```
AmazonCognitoIdentity identityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(
    new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key_id", "secret_access_key")
);
identityClient.GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity()
```

-

```
AmazonCognitoIdentity identityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(
    new CognitoAWSCredentials ("IDENTITY_POOL_ID", "REGION_NAME");
);
identityClient.GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity()
```

Although most examples on the internet show BasicAWSCredentials being used to instantiate a CognitoIdentityClient, but the method signature in the doc says it accepts `AWSCredentials` class - both `BasicAWSCredentials` as well as `CognitoAWSCredentials` are subclasses of the `AWSCredentials` class. Hence, i am assuming both should be working normally i guess???

I am trying to understand how will this difference, impact the following:

- privileges,
- timeouts,
- etc?

API reference for cognitoIdentityClient constructors is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=CognitoIdentity/TCognitoIdentityCognitoIdentityClient.html&tocid=Amazon_CognitoIdentity_AmazonCognitoIdentityClient

Answer (score 2):

In client device you should instantiate `AmazonCognitoIdentityClient` client using `CognitoAWSCredentials`. Using STS service, AWS client will obtain temporary credentials that will let the client assume the role you previously defined in your identity pool. Typically this role would have very limited access to your AWS resources. (S3 upload to a specific bucket etc.) This is like giving out to people a special type of your car key which can only turn on the music system, not the engine.

On the other hand `GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` is a special API call that needs developer credentials. You should never deploy developer credentials to any client device and you should keep it only on your server. Once you instantiate a `AmazonCognitoIdentityClient` using developer credentials on your server, you can expose a REST endpoint for clients to obtain OpenId token (for a given identity id or creating a new one). Let's assume that your users are logging in to your API using their username and password and you return them a custom access token which is stored in your database. After that your endpoint may implement this logic:

1. Fetch unique identifier for your user using custom token (user id, username, e-mail etc.)
2. Use `LookupDeveloperIdentity` and find out the identityId for the given username.
3. Use `GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` with found identityId and send back to the client. So they can "login" to that identityId.
4. If this user has not any identityId assigned to its username, create a new one and send back.

As you see developer AWS tokens are enabling a couple of sensitive API calls. Now let us assume that client had developer access token and thus has access to `GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` call. Then they would be able to generate OpenId tokens, switch to other people's identities easily and access their private data.

If you don't use developer authenticated identities (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html) you do not need `GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` mechanism though. If you are using only public authentication methods (Twitter, Facebook etc.) you should ignore the second paragraph and use `CognitoAWSCredentials`.

Comment: Can you please clarify about this line? ***"This endpoint would accept a custom identity token, check its validity and send an OpenId token back to the client."*** Did you mean the REST endpoint will accept a custom IdentityToken or a custom IdentityID? In this scenario, we either have a OpenIDToken or an IdentityID. Which one did you mean should be the input to the REST endpoint?

Comment: I edited my answer. I don't know how good I can explain because this Cognito is a real headache. For us also it was very complicated and it took time to understand. It is not an easy service..

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Yes cognito is quite tricky. Have another question in case you might know about it. The `GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` returns a IdentityId and a OpenIDToken. Where is the OpenIDToken used anyways? In the federated authentication auth flow, my next call would be GetCredentialsForIdentity() which (according to the docs here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html) needs only the `IdentityId` - it does not need the `OpenIdToken` that is returned by `GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity`. What do we need it for?

Comment: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1YVAQ4NZKBWF5/Amazon-Cognito-Announcing-Developer-Authenticated-Identities here you can find answer to this.

Comment: Ok. So according to this guide ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html ), after authenticating via a external provider, we can either choose the **Enhanced (simplified) Authflow** (which calls the `cognito.GetCredentialsForIdentity()` function that doesnt need the *OpenIDToken*) or we can choose the **Basic (Classic) Authflow** (which calls the `sts.AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity()` function that requires the *OpenIDToken*). In that case, i guess the *OpenIDToken* is of not much relevance if we choose the **Enhanced Authflow**. Am i on the right track?

Comment: can you kindly validate if my understanding is correct on this regard? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As described in Çağatay's answer, the BasicAwsCredentials are instantiated with your developer credentials. What he described about when to use each constructor is absolutely correct in every case other than developer authenticated identities.

Since this code will be deployed on a back end service, it's exposure is less of a concern. Mobile clients will communicate with this server and get the token from it, with which they will get credentials. The credentials are never exposed to the user in this pattern.

As you can see in the [Cognito documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html), the sample has BasicAwsCredentials. An end to end sample is visible in [this blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en).